# How to translate the Month and Day in Date-picker pop-out calendar for Angular Formly?

Tags: ngx-translate, angular-formly

I have integrated Date picker into my angular version 8 and it is working as expected. My form uses internationalization to which *ngx-formly* supports with the help of ngx-translate. I would like to know how these controls date picker options get translated because workaround or any sample example for it is not present anywhere.

My application has an option to change language and everything translate except for the calendar that pops-out when picking dates for **Angular Formly** date-picker.

These are the *providers* for my date-picker component:

```
providers: [
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatepickerComponent),
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: NgbDateAdapter,
  useClass: DatepickerDateAdapter
},
{
  provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
  useClass: DatepickerDateParserFormatter
},
{
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatepickerComponent),
  multi: true
}
```

]

How to translate the *months* and "*days* for the calendar that pops-out for the date-picker for **Angular Formly**?